# VLC cannot play a non-UDF mastered DVD

Tags: vlc-media-player, dvd

The VLC player cannot play a DVD disk on my computer. Whenever I click the menu "Media > Open disk..." from the player or "Play with VLC media player" from the context menu, the error prompt "Cannot play a non-UDF mastered DVD" is shown as below:

[image: screenshot]

I tried KMPlayer and it had no problem of playing. I have installed `libdvdcss-1.4.2.tar.bz2` and `libdvdnav-6.0.0.tar.bz2` as per the instruction of this [article](https://www.5kplayer.com/video-music-player/solve-vlc-cant-play-dvd-problems.htm) via the Ubuntu shell on Windows 10 by entering these commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

but I'm not sure if the libs got installed correctly because the same error recurred after restarting VLC. I tried to Google the problem as well as searching the [forum](https://forum.videolan.org/search.php?keywords=cannot+play+non-UDF+mastered+DVD&sid=f9b65c30a427c7d78499100f32a87820) and here on this site and didn't find any related discussion. I don't want to convert the DVD to formats other than an ISO image because I want to preserve the DVD control while viewing the videos in it. I did make an ISO image out of the DVD disk with [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), and it's the same problem with the image when played with VLC.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works in many cases (not all though, in some cases some or all menus or invisible, but still the button locations react to clicks):

**Preparations for VLC when u cannot access folders on the DVD**

If it's a real DVD: Create an ISO from it (u can user for example 'PowerISO' to do this. Skip this if it's already an ISO of a non UDF-mastered disk or if you can access the "VIDEO_TS" folder on the DVD due to a firmware hack etc.
Now mount the ISO as drive (Windows can do this natively).

**Open the VIDEO_TS folder as medium**

Open VLC, Click "Open Medium", instead of choosing the mounted ISO's drive or the DVD drive as root, choose the VIDEO_TS folder within as playback drive. The DVD should now play.

If it's movie, the menus aren't that important. Language, Subtitles etc. can be selected within VLC itself. If the menus are invisible, the locations of the buttons are still clickable usually - but might be problematic when it's something like a training dvd with heavily nested menus etc. In such a case, I would suggest to rip the DVD with MakeMKV or something else OR -see below- switch to another player.

**If Menus are really important (Alternative Player)**

For Windows users that really need the menus, which aren't shown in VLC when using the workaround above. I don't remember right now, for what other platforms KMPlayer is available, so this is only ensured for windows users.

KMPlayer can play also ISO mounts, simply open the "Video_TS.IFO" file in the "VIDEO_TS" folder of the mounted ISO of the DVD to start the playback. It will show the menus that are invisible within VLC. But again, this requires access to the folder structure of the DVD (so depending on the DVD and your drive or better its firmware, it might be still required to create an ISO from it or alter your drive's firmware if possible - **but be informed, that firmware changes you do on your own risk!**)

Answer (score 0):

The standard disc format that preceded UDF is called
[ISO-9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660),
which is probably the recording format of your disc.

Unfortunately, it seems like VLC cannot do it.

In the videolan wiki [What can VLC do?](https://wiki.videolan.org/What_can_VLC_do%3F/),
I found this comment :

> The kinds of Compact Disc formats supported are CDRWIN's BIN/CUE format, cdrdao's TOC format, and a limited set of Nero (NRG) formats.
>
> (libcdio also supports ISO-9660 image reading, but at present there is no VLC access plugin which uses it. DVD's images follow the UDF format and there is some UDF support in libcdio. It is possible that will get added in the future; volunteers are most welcome.)

You are then obliged to use another player that supports that old format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while running my DVD from VLC media player. Instead of using VLC, I used windows media player (default software provided by windows) to run and it worked.
Try using some other player than VLC. Hope that might help

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem with VLC 3.

As a Fedora user, I managed to view my video with "videos" software, a basic player installed by default on Fedora core.

Hope this helps